# Add products on shopping cart

Tags: codeigniter, e-commerce, shopping-cart

Friends, I am developing an e-commerce website (using Codeigniter).

After the customer fill out the amount of products and click "Buy", only products with the field "quantity" are to be filled in cart. Can you help me?

**HTML:**

```
<form>
<ul class="products-list">
    <li class="product">
        <input type="hidden" class="product_id" value="1">
        <span class="product-name">Product 1</span>
        <span class="product-value">$ 100</span> 
        <span>Qnt. <input type="text" class="quantity"></span> 
    </li>
        <li class="product">
        <input type="hidden" class="product_id" value="2">
        <span class="product-name">Product 2</span>
        <span class="product-value">$ 100</span> 
        <span>Qnt. <input type="text" class="quantity"></span> 
    </li>
</ul>
<button>Buy</button>
</form>
```

---

**jQuery:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/cart/add/'+product_id+'/'+quantity,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function( data ){
        if ( data != false ) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
});
```

---

**My PHP Code:**

```
public function addItem( $product_id, $quantity){ 
    $product = $this->Produto_model->getById($product_id); 
    $this->carrinho->setItem($product, $quantity); 
    echo json_encode($this->carrinho); 
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What works and what doesn't? Where does it go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

HTML:

```
<form id="form-cart">
    <ul class="products-list">
        <li class="product">
            <input type="hidden" class="product_id" value="1">
            <span class="product-name">Product 1</span>
            <span class="product-value">$ 100</span> 
            <span>Qnt. <input type="text" class="quantity" value="1"></span> 
        </li>
            <li class="product">
            <input type="hidden" class="product_id" value="2">
            <span class="product-name">Product 2</span>
            <span class="product-value">$ 100</span> 
            <span>Qnt. <input type="text" class="quantity" value="1"></span> 
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button id="form-cart-btn">Buy</button>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#form-cart #form-cart-btn").click(function(){
        form = $("#form-cart");

        items = [];

        form.find('li').each(function(i, e){
            _e  = $(e);
            qty = parseInt(_e.find('.quantity').val());

            if(isNaN(parseFloat(qty)) || ! isFinite(qty) || qty == 0)
                return;

            id = _e.find('.product_id').val();
            items.push('item[' + id + ']=' + qty);
        });

        items = items.join('&');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/cart/add/?' + items,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response)
            {
                if(response.status != 'success')
                    return false;

                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Cart Controller:

```
class Cart extends CI_Controller
{
    public function add()
    { 
        $items = isset($_GET['items']) ? $_GET['items'] : array();

        foreach($items as $product_id => $qty)
        {
            $product = $this->Produto_model->getById($product_id);
            if( ! $product)
            {
                ++$i;
                continue;
            }
            $this->carrinho->setItem($product, $qty);
            ++$i;
        }

        header("Content-type: application/json");
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success'));
        exit();
    }  
}
```

Comment: Ok, and what I do in routes.php file?

Currently looks like this:

$route['cart/add/(:num)/(:num)'] = "front/products/addItem/$1/$2";

Comment: `$route['cart/add/'] = "front/products/addItem/"`